# css animation ignores rotation

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to make an animation, where few elements would appear bigger than they are and shrink back to normal.

Here's what I've got:

**One of the elements**

```
#element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38%;
  height: auto;
  animation: ani 250ms ease-in;
  -webkit-animation: ani 250ms ease-in;
  transform: rotate(82deg);
}
```

**And keyframe**

```
@keyframes ani {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="element" src="img.svg">
  <img id="element2" src="img2.svg">
</div>
```

The problem is that whenever the animation starts, elements appear as they never been rotated and rotates only after animation ends. How could I force them to rotate before the animation?

Comment: do you have html? so we can test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should combine the rotation code with transform in animation as well. basically `rotate` and `scale` both are the values of `transform` property, so if you only use scale in the animation, it will override `rotate` value and will only show the `scale`.

```css
#element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38%;
  height: auto;
  animation: ani 250ms ease-in;
  -webkit-animation: ani 250ms ease-in;
  transform: rotate(82deg);
}

@keyframes ani {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(82deg);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(82deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0) rotate(82deg);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) rotate(82deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="element" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
  <img id="element2" src="http://smallbusinessbc.ca/wp-content/themes/sbbcmain/images/circle-icons/icon-education.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: is it the only way? E. g. if i have 10 elements with different rotation angles I shoul describe a keyframe for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your rotate into the keyframes:

```
#element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38%;
  height: auto;
  animation: ani 250ms ease-in;
  -webkit-animation: ani 250ms ease-in;
}

@keyframes ani {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.5) rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0) rotate(82deg);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) rotate(82deg);
    }
}
```